# Timer stops the program before it is over

Tags: python, timer

I coded a timer to last for 1 minute before the program continues, but the timer keeps on stopping at around 12 seconds and prevents the program from moving forward.

I read somewhere that the `time.sleep` function doesn't work if the system clock changes, and to replace it with `time.monotonic`, but doing that just bugged my code more.
Here is my code for the timer:

```
import time
import datetime


def countdown(m, s):
    total_seconds = m * 60 + s
    while total_seconds > 0:
        timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = total_seconds)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        total_seconds -= 1
    if s == 5:
        print("Go!")
        print("")
    else:
        print("Alright, are you done yet? (yes/no)")
```

I have the `if` statement at the end because I used the timer in two instances only: One was when I was counting down five seconds, and the other one was a timer that was a minute long. I wanted them to print different messages at the end. I do not know threading, nor do I think I need it in this specific program.

Here is the code where the countdown is called:

```
if require7 == "no":
    print("Okay, I'll be nice.")
    print("(Press any key to continue)")
    input()
    print("Don't tell anybody else, but I'm giving you one minute to do those pushups.")
    input()
    print("I'll count.")
    input()
    print("Ready? I'll countdown 'till I start.")
    input()
    m = 0
    s = 5
    countdown(m, s)
    # Inputs for hours, minutes, seconds on timer
    m = 1
    s = 0
    countdown(m, s)
    input()
    if (input=="yes" or "no"):
        print("Well, sorry, but you're not eligible.")
        print("You do not have qualities that we are looking for.")
        print("Goodbye.")
    else:
        print("I don't know what you just entered, but you're not eligible.")
        print("You do not have qualities that we are looking for.")
        print("Goodbye.")
```

Comment: Can you also show the code where you call `countdown`?

Comment: If I add `countdown(1, 0)` at the end this seems to work fine.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'll add it to the end of my post. It works for me sometimes but most of the time it stops at ~12 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import time
import datetime

def countdown(m, s):
    try:
        total_seconds = m * 60 + s
        while total_seconds > 0:
            timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds=total_seconds)
            print(f"Time remaining: {timer}", end="\r")
            time.sleep(1)
            total_seconds -= 1

        print("\nGo!")
        print("")
        response = input("Alright, are you done yet? (yes/no): ").strip().lower()
        if response == "yes":
            print("Great! You're done.")
        else:
            print("Please complete your task.")

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter valid minutes and seconds.")

# Example usage:
countdown(0, 10)  # Countdown from 0 minutes and 10 seconds
```

Output 1:

```
Time remaining: 0:00:01
Go!

Alright, are you done yet? (yes/no): yes
Great! You're done.
```

Output 2:

```
Time remaining: 0:00:01
Go!

Alright, are you done yet? (yes/no): no
Please complete your task.
```

Comment: Any specific reason for downvote ?

Comment: I don't know, I tried to upvote it but it said I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question why the timer stops after 12 seconds instead of a minute.